# OpenCV whole Images to bytes without saving to disk

Tags: python, opencv

Basically, I want to add a few bytes to my new PNG image file. An example case is like the following code:

```
img = open("example.png", "rb") # Open images and read as binary
hex = img.read().hex() # Read images as Bytes to Hexadecimal.
add_hex = hex+"7feab1e74a4bdb755cca" # Add some bytes to it (as hex)
to_bytes_img = bytes.fromhex(add_hex) # Convert hex to bytes
with open("example2.png", "wb") as f: # Write images
   f.write(to_bytes_img)
```

But, the problem is, I have a special case that requires me to perform the above operation using OpenCV (CV2). Where `cv2.imread()` only reads and stores Pixels as a numpy array (an array of pixels, not the whole file).

Then, I want to write that image into a new file `cv2.imwrite()`, which will rebuild the image and save the PNG on disk. My question is, how do I add some bytes to the PNG image file (in buffer/memory), before the `cv2.imwrite()` operation.

I could probably do it with `with open()` as above, but that would be very inefficient opening, writing, opening, writing to disk again.

Comment: have a look at `cv.imdecode`. You can decode directly your bytes in memory assuming you're not corrupting the image

Comment: forget "hex". that's nothing but a readable representation. the data itself is `bytes`. -- use `open()` with **append** mode to *append* the stuff you want to go there